# Conceptual ambiguity between "/MD /MT " and "dll lib"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I am perplexed by the concept between the run-time library option on Windows. I thought I know the difference between lib and dll. The lib will be compiled to your code and the dll will be loaded dynamically on execution. But when I compile a lib, I am obliged to make a choice between `/MD` and `/MT`. On msdn.microsoft.com it is said that:

> Applications compiled with /MD are statically linked to MSVCRT.lib.
>   This library provides a layer of code that enables the linker to
>   resolve external references. The actual working code is contained in
>   MSVCRversionnumber.DLL, which must be available at run time to
>   applications linked with MSVCRT.lib.

At this time I cannot catch the idea that when I using a lib I also need to dynamically load a dll. It seems like that using `/MD` option to build a lib will result in a "dynamical lib", or using `/MT` option to build a dll will result in a "static dll".

So what's the difference between "`/MD` vs `/MT`" and "lib vs dll"?

Comment: /MT is only appropriate when you create a program that does not use any modules.  Its only advantage is that the program will be easy to deploy onto another machine, just a single EXE file to copy.  When you use it in one that uses DLLs then you already lost that advantage.  And have to deal with the fact that the process has more than one copy of the C runtime.  Which is a very, very risky proposition, the CRT has lots of global state.  Something as basic as `errno` cannot work correctly.  Just never do that, it is as simple as that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A key aspect of this is differentiating between the build/compile time issues and the runtime issues.

At build time, the compiler and linker need sufficient information on how to compile and construct the code; data definitions, function locations etc. The header files provide most of that detail for the compiler, the linker needs to be able to locate the functions<sup>1</sup> to complete the process.

If the dll is provided with a lib as well (as is the case with [`/MD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.120).aspx)), this lib contains the minimum required code for the linker to find the functions required and some additional code to load the dll at runtime. A program can be made that does not link with a lib (even though there is a dll), you will then need to load the dll at runtime (via [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx)) and fix up the pointers (via [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx)) to the functions<sup>1</sup> you need to call. With a C++ library that is difficult, hence it is generally not attempted, the name mangling make this harder (with a C library it is generally much easier).

If the lib is a static lib with no associated dll (for the runtime this is [`/MT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.120).aspx)), then the lib contains all the code needed to run and execute its given functionality. The linker links all the required code up into the target and no additional runtime loading is required.

<sup>1</sup> I loosely use the word functions here, but it includes all externals as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your reply, together with JasonB's, clearly explained this the detail of this problem. Now I have successfully compiled the program and realize what happened behind my selection of those build options. Your are surely an expert on this.

Comment: @Niall: Thanks, would calling an MD built library from a second MT built library work using the `LoadLibrary` trick?

Comment: @Rika. In concept possibly/probably. But that doesn't make too much sense to me with the runtime libraries, just use the version you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate it. the reason behind this is, Pytorch's C++ library(libtorch) doesn't support MTd build that's why I asked that question as I couldn't come up with anything else to circumvent this issue.

Comment: @Rika. If the library doesn’t expose any C++ runtime types, or manage memory you allocate, or vice versa, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases the application will be statically linked with a `.lib` file, but if `/MT` is used then it will be linked with `libcmt.lib` or `libcmtd.lib` (Release/Debug), which contain the C run-time itself, whereas if `/MD` is used it will be linked with `msvcrt.lib` or `msvcrtd.lib`, which are just import libraries for the DLL and do not contain the run-time.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=vs.120).aspx for details.

(Note that in VS2015 the libraries have been split and have new names; the C99-portion names are `libucrt.lib`, `libucrtd.lib`, `ucrt.lib`, and `ucrtd.lib`, respectively.)

Comment: Oh, thanks. I see it. So even a lib can only be statically linked to a program, but with /MD option the lib, which we use, it self has a dependence on the corresponding dll file.

Comment: The import lib file is is used for load-time dynamic linking; it makes it easier to use the DLL without having to call `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` for every function you want to use. If you don't want load-time dynamic linking (e.g. so your program will use a DLL if it's available but survive without it if not) then you have to use run-time dynamic linking with the above calls. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681914(v=vs.85).aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Every `DLL` has a corresponding `.lib` file too. The linker links against the `.lib` file, which has the necessary instructions that indicates which symbols need to be loaded at run time from a `DLL`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if every dll has a corresponding .lib file, where is the .lib file of my own compiled dll? Or this rule is just for the c run-time dll?